# TensorFlow Concat

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, keras

I am trying to rebuild the 3D U-Net in this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06650.pdf

And unfortunately, when I get to the first merge, I get the following error from Keras:

ValueError: "concat" mode can only merge layers with matching output shapes except for the concat axis. Layer shapes: [(None, 512, 14, 8, 10), (None, 256, 15, 8, 10)]

I understand that based on this thread:

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/633

The following is true:

> the concat axis is the axis along which to concatenate the two tensors.
>   Lets say you have two three-dimensional tensors of shape (2,3,5) and (2,3,7). Then you can only concatenate them along the third (zero based index: 2) axis, because then – figuratively – the two "faces" of the "cuboid" that you "glue together" are each 2-by-3 and only those fit. So you need to set concat_axis = 2 (or -1, since it is the last one) resulting in a new tensor (2,3,12).
>   Typically in a NN you would merge along the axis of the features, which depends on the type of layers you use and the implementation in keras. If you are not sure you can try out a few, most likely only one will work for the reason given above. If the figurative "faces don't fit" you will get an error message like the one in my opening post."

Which means I should be merging on the 14 and 15, which are axis=0, correct?

Can someone help explain what I am missing in this setup?

Thanks!

Comment: In `concat` layer, you should have only one non-matching dimension, which will also be the axis along which you concatenate. In your case, there are two - `(512, 256)` and `(14,15)`. You cannot concatenate these two tensors. As far as which axis you should concatenate along, I really don't know. It depends on your method.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you if you also posted your code.